# python create file but out put as none

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a program that generate list of student and random password, then write it into a file, I know I should have return value , but I couldn't figure out how to get a return, here is my code

```
import random

animals = ["rat","ox","tiger","rabbit","dragon","snake","horse","sheep","monkey","rooster","dog","pig"]

colours = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet","black","white"]

def number():
    number = random.randint(0,100)

    return str(number)

def pw():   
    pw = '1'.join([random.choice(colours)+random.choice(animals)+random.choice(number())])
    return pw

def student_name_and_pw():
    name = 30
    while name <=90:
        print("student",name,":",pw())
        name = name + 1

file = open("C:\\Users\\ming\\Desktop\\nameandpw.txt","w")
print(file)
file.write(str(student_name_and_pw()))
file.close()
```

when I open file, it just says none.

Comment: Function `student_name_and_pw` returns a `None` (because it does not return anything else). That's why.

Comment: You function should have a `return` statement if you want it to return anything...

Comment: I know I should have a return value , I just don't where and how to add return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the string you want to write into the file in your method `student_name_and_pw` and return it

```
def student_name_and_pw():
    name = 30
    content = ""
    while name <=90:
        content += "student %s : %s\n" % (name, pw())
        name = name + 1
    return content
```

Comment: thank you so much! This work perfectly! May I have one more question? The code I have suppose to give random number between 1 to 100, but all result I got is single digit, which is 1 to 9, no idea why it happenes.

Comment: instead of +random.choice(number())  do +number()

Comment: thank you for noticing me , new to this , forgive me.